# Exiting an application that is blocked waiting for an incoming pipe stream

Tags: c#, named-pipes, namedpipeserverstream

I have an application that runs a NamedPipeServerStream in a thread and waits for connections on it like so:

```
NamedPipeServerStream pipeServerTemp = new NamedPipeServerStream(PIP_NAME, PipeDirection.InOut, 254);
pipeServerTemp.WaitForConnection();
```

The application is always waiting for new connections, but when I try to kill the app the process hangs on the call to WaitForConnection.

I've tried aborting the thread in question but it doesn't kill the application.

How can I tell the NamedPipeServerStream to stop listening for connections?

**EDIT:**

I can see that NamedPipeServerStream has a method called `EndWaitForConnection` but it needs a reference to an `IAsynchResult`, where would I get that object?

Comment: Close the pipe, catch the ObjectDisposedException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution I was looking for in the answer [to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607872/what-is-a-good-way-to-shutdown-threads-blocked-on-namedpipeserverwaitforconnect).

For what it's worth I went for the simple solution of connecting to the Stream and then immediately closing the connection rather than making it asynchronous.